# AWS Alexa Skill Freeze/Thaw

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa Skill that should make a **PATCH** Request to my Database to change a field for the current user. When I trigger the intent in the alexa developer console, alexa sometimes replies "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" and the PATCH request goes through successfully. Other times Alexa responds "Ok, we will upgrade your number.", however in this case the http PATCH request doesn't go through. I think this has something to do with the **"Freeze/Thaw"** Cycle (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) but I am not sure. When I check the device logs in the developer console it just says: 
An error occurred while issuing a SpeechletRequest for  (requestId [amzn1.echo-api.request......]
All other http requests work completely fine.

```
'upgrade': async function () {

  const token = this.event.context.System.user.accessToken;
var uniqueId = String(token);

  let upgradeNumber = buildPostData(10);

this.emit(':tell','Ok, we will upgrade your number.');

 try {
       await postData(uniqueId,upgradeNumber); 
    }
    catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
}

},
```

Comment: I still haven't found a solution.... All other https requests work fine except this one? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try moving `try catch` with its code before `this.emit`? If I recall correctly, after `emit`, response is sent and sometimes your request to `postData` might not have enough time to resolve. This would be my guess from what I see.